# How is it called to the one that anonymizes?

Tags: word-request, nouns

I cannot found this online. That one that anonymizes is an anonymator, an anonymizator or anything else?

Comment: [Anonymizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymizer)

Comment: Great, I feel I was so close... thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about a *person* that conceals their identity or are you asking about the internet tools described by @Justin?

Comment: @chasly A person, is not the same word?

Comment: It does not.  Anonymizer is the internet tool. I don't know a single word for a person that hides their identity.  Have you tried a bilingual dictionary?

Comment: @james Sorry, no. I am not looking for the word for a person who hides his/her identity, but for the person that carries out the process of anonymizing things.

Comment: Can you explain further.... Is this a job?  What sort of things does this person anonymize.  Can you create an example sentence?  Is there a word in your native language (and what does your favourite dictionary tell you is the translation into English)?

Comment: For example, to anonymize a book you don't need a person to do anything.  You just don't put the author's name on the front.  That's not an action, it's an inaction.

Comment: @james I think anonymizer can be the answer because I am looking for the name of the person that does something similar to what internet tools do. These days many people have the task of making data anonymous, i.e., making sure that no one can identify individuals in the data. Data can be: trajectories, images, names, numbers, anything.

Comment: Example sentence: "I anonymize data, I am an ...."

Comment: Your last two comments are what we needed at the start. Now that you have given this information I can answer your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant information from the comments. Comments are meant to be [temporary](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anonymizer is a tool that hides the identity of a computer from the server.  It allows a person to browse the internet anonymously and privately.

I'd understand "data anonymizer" as a description of a person, but in actual use, it almost always refers to a tool that the person uses.  I can find little evidence of it being a job title that someone might have, rather it is a task that is done by people with different titles

> I am the data manager for the company.  I anonymize data before it is distributed and ensure GDPR compliance

> I usually get a postdoc to anonymize the clinical data before it is archived.

> I anonymize data, I am a personal information compliance officer.

In practice we would not normally talk about a data anonymizer, except as a computer tool.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for the name of the person that does something similar to
> what internet tools do. These days many people have the task of making
> data anonymous, i.e., making sure that no one can identify individuals
> in the data. Data can be: trajectories, images, names, numbers,
> anything. Example sentence: "I anonymize data, I am a ...."

**redactor**  or **reaction co-ordinator**

> Definition of **redactor** : one who redacts a work
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redactor
>
> Definition of **redact** transitive verb
>
> 1: ...
> 2: to select or adapt (as **by obscuring or removing sensitive
> information**) for publication or release broadly : EDIT 3: to obscure
> or remove (text) from a document prior to publication or release
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redacts

Note: If you search online for ***redaction co-ordinator***, you will find that there are vacancies available! https://duckduckgo.com/?q=redaction+co-ordinator&atb=v245-1&ia=web